# Return all days in between strtotime "now" and "+2 weeks"

Tags: php, date, strtotime

How can I return all the days in between two strtotime functions? I am sure I would need a foreach loop but not sure how to go about it.

```
        echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("now")); 
        echo "<br />";
        echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("+2 weeks"));
```

Comment: for loop with a count of 14 increment each day by 1

Comment: The unix timestamp returned by `strtotime` gives you seconds.  There are 86400 seconds in a day.  That is your `for` loop increment.  Do the `date` conversion inside the loop.

Comment: "There are 86400 seconds in a day." not always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) iterator class. Example from the documentation:

```
$begin = new DateTime( '2007-12-31' );
$end = new DateTime( '2009-12-31 23:59:59' );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('last thursday of next month');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
  echo $dt->format( "l Y-m-d H:i:s\n" );
}
```

Comment: looks like that did it `                $begin = new DateTime("now");
                $end = new DateTime("+2 weeks");

                $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
                $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

                foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
                    echo $dt->format( "l Y-m-d H:i:s\n" );
                }` thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the basic idea ..

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {

    echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("now + $i day")); 
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```